# How to prove this inequality $ \left|\frac{{\sin x}}{x} - \frac{{\sin y}}{y}\right| \le \sqrt {2\left|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\right|}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

$$
\left|\frac{{\sin x}}{x} - \frac{{\sin y}}{y}\right| \leqslant \sqrt {2\left|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\right|}
$$

I tried to prove this by using mean value theorem, but I failed. Could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake... I have corrected my question.

Comment: In the future, once you have posted a question and received answers for that question, please do not edit your question to ask something different (even if it was just a mistake). Ask a new question, and link to the old one in your new question.

Answer (score 7):

It is not true in general. For example, take

$x=\pi$, $y=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Then 
$|x\sin y - y\sin x| = \pi > \sqrt 2 |x - y|= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}$

Answer (score 3):

For $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$, define $g(x,y)=x\sin y$. So $|\nabla g|=\sqrt{\sin^2y+x^2\cos^2y}\le1$

So by MVT $|g(x,y)-g(y,x)|\le 1\times\sqrt{(x-y)^2+(y-x)^2}=\sqrt{2}|x-y|$.

$$\therefore|x\sin y-y\sin x|\le\sqrt{2}|x-y|\;\forall\;x,y\in[0,1]$$

Answer (score 2):

This only deals with $0\leq x<y\leq \pi$. Let $\phi(t)=\frac{\sin t}{t}$, so that
$\phi'(t)=\frac{t\cos t -\sin t}{t^2}=\big(\cos t -\frac{\sin t}{t}\big)\frac{1}{t}$. By Cauchy-Schwartz's inequality
$$\begin{align}
\Big|\int^y_x\big(\cos t -\frac{\sin t}{t}\big)\frac{1}{t}\,dt\Big|&\leq \sqrt{\int^y_x\big|\cos t -\frac{\sin t}{t}\big|^2\,dt}\sqrt{\int^y_x\frac{1}{t^2}\,dt}\\
&=\sqrt{\Big|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\Big|}\,\sqrt{\int^y_x\big|\cos t -\frac{\sin t}{t}\big|^2\,dt}
\end{align}$$
For $0\leq x<y\leq\pi$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\Big|\frac{\sin x}{x}-\frac{\sin y}{y}\Big|&\leq\sqrt{\Big|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\Big|}\sqrt{\int^\pi_0\big|\cos t -\frac{\sin t}{t}\big|^2\,dt}
\end{align}$$
A numerical estimation gives  $\int^\pi_0\big|\cos t -\frac{\sin t}{t}\big|^2\,dt\approx1.570796\ldots<1.6=\frac{8}{5}$. It follows that
$$\begin{align}
\Big|\frac{\sin x}{x}-\frac{\sin y}{y}\Big|&\leq \sqrt{\frac{8}{5}\Big|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\Big|}
\end{align}
$$

Outside that range the problem seems more difficult

Answer (score 0):

For some $\psi$ we have
$$|x\sin y - y\sin x| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}|\sin(x+\psi)|\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
And it is easy to see, that
$$x^2+y^2\le 2(x-y)^2$$

Comment: $\cos\psi={-y\over\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$,  $\sin\psi={x\over \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ but how is $\cos x=\sin y$ in general?

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake.