# Prove $|x\sin\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)-y\sin\Big(\frac{1}{y}\Big)|\leq\sqrt{2|x-y|}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Prove that:

$$\Big|x\sin\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)-y\sin\Big(\frac{1}{y}\Big)\Big|\leq\sqrt{2|x-y|}$$

**My attempt**

I have prove that $$F(x,y)=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{|x-y|^a}$$ $$f(x)=x\sin\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)$$have a bound if and only if $a\leq\frac{1}{2}$.

But I can't prove that $F(x)\leq\sqrt2$, if $a=\frac{1}{2}$.

So I want to get some help. Thank you.

**Relative Questtion**

I found some questons which is related to my question.

[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523297/how-to-prove-this-inequality-bigx-sin-frac1x-y-sin-frac1y-big2?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392037/how-to-prove-this-inequality-left-frac-sin-xx-frac-sin-yy-rig?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646644/inequality-leftx-sin-frac1x-y-sin-frac1y-right-leq-sqrt2x-y)

Comment: Use the mean value theorem!

Comment: @Dr Mean value theorem can't prove the coefficient $\sqrt2$.

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner Do you have some idea about this question？